# Want to make my oracle forms to access online oracle database

Tags: oracle10g

A guy made an **oracle based web forms** and setup oracle database in my computer 3 years before.
Now I want to make my **database online**.
So that I could access via my two computers.
I do not even know basic thing about oracle.

If any one could tell me how to do this?
someone told me I have to do it via live IP, dedicated server or VPS?

Could any one can give me idea from where should I start?
Should I buy a **dedicated server  or VPS** or any other way to do this.

Comment: Suggestion: look into online hosting companies (e.g. Oracle (https://cloud.oracle.com/database), Amazon EC2 (http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), Amazon RDS (http://aws.amazon.com/rds/), etc.)

Comment: they are too much expensive is their any cheapest solution?

Comment: These are probably the cheapest options, I think. An Amazon EC2 instance would be about $30 per month give or take, plus when you start out you get a free usage allotment. There's no free lunch, though.